# How to shrink the size of arc/ellipse in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

### Problem

I want to draw arc on HTML Canvas, by which an image is masked.

I could draw the arc, which has an animation of expansion.

But, I couldn't make it shrink or smaller...

What's the problem?

Google Chrome dev tool doesn't expose any errors.

Thansk in advance.

### Codes

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="184"></canvas>

    <script>
      var w = 350;
      var h = 184;
      var c = 0;

      window.onload = function () {
        draw();
      }

      function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if(!canvas || !canvas.getContext) return false;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "MY_IMAGE.jpg";
        img.onload = () => {
          setInterval(() => {
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.save();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(0, 0, w - c, Math.PI * 2, 0, false); // Doens't work!
            // ctx.arc(0, 0, c, Math.PI * 2, 0, false);  // Works! But I want to make the arc smaller, not bigger...

            ctx.clip();

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 350, 184);

            c += 1;
            if(c >= w) {
              c = 0;
            }
          }, 20);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine. It just appears to not be working because you are not clearing your canvas between re-draw frames. Once something is drawn on canvas it stays there. So the image is shrinking but you aren’t seeing it because the bigger image is already drawn and stays on the screen.

Add `ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)`

Before you draw the image. You also don’t need the save and restore methods.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Thanks for the answer. I appreciate for your description.